# iOS/Django: How to perform dual authentication?

Tags: python, ios, django, swift, webview

I had created an API that I use to get processed data from a postgresql db in the form of json. I am able to authenticate the user via the api using the Django Rest Framework and get an authentication token for the same. Now in some pages of my app, I need to display pages in a webview from the web app. These pages require a csrf token in order to be accessed. The csrf token is generated on the submit button of the login on the web app.

I can extract the csrf token from the cookies generated after login. So here's what I'm hoping to accomplish. Whenever I login from the login screen on my app, I want to programmatically create a webview in the background, fill in the login and password and tap the submit button in the web page. I will then proceed to extract the token from the cookies.

Most of the parts I have down, I am not able to figure out how to programmatically fill in the webview and hit the submit button. (The reason I want to hit the submit button is because the view checks if the request is a post and ajax). Can anyone shed some light on how I go about performing dual authentication in this manner?

Comment: Why don't you wanna just use the same token you use in the app, to access whatever you need in the web view?

Comment: The token generated for the api is different from the csrf token and session generated by the webview. The csrf token will only be generated by the browser once the webview has been rendered

Comment: You can create a view where you take API key and login the user to be logged in as Session based, then redirect to whatever place you need, whatever you set in `?next=` param.

Comment: And yes, even though the API key and session + CSRF have different tokens, you still can use the API with the same API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is curious, I managed to perform dual authentication via a hidden webview at the login. I hit the api url to get the api auth token, and simultaneously hit the web app url on my webview. I fill in the username, password and tap the submit button through code

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    print("loadFinished")
    let loadUsername = "var emailText = document.getElementById('email'); emailText.value = '\(username)';"
    let loadPass = "var passText =  document.getElementById('password'); passText.value = '\(pass)';"
    let submitAction = "var passFields = document.getElementById('login_button'); passFields.click();"

    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: loadUsername)
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: loadPass)
    webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: submitAction)
    print("Executed!")

    let req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://app.xyz.io/abc/")!)
    if tf != true {
        webView.loadRequest(req)
        tf = true
    }

}
```

After my request loads and authenticates successfully, I merely retrieve the csrf token and sessionid from the session's cookies.

Hope this helped someone!